# Issue in running a client script in NetSuite suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, clientscript

I have a client script in NetSuite 2.0 which is already running ,but if I am making any changes to it, the new changes are not getting reflected the script is still running with the old code.
Even if I try to add single log.debug it is not getting reflected when the script is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to check:

- first thing is if you are running in the UI then your browser probably cached the script so a ctrl-F5 to reload the page should fix things.
- second you may not be updating the correct file. If you navigate to the script definition you can open the code directly and verify your changes are there.

Comment: I checked this things everything seems to be correct still the changes are not reflecting

Comment: How do you know the script is currently running? Does it have some behaviour that you can see in the page? If you un-deploy the script you think is running does that behaviour go away?

Comment: The issue was of cache it is working fine after clearing the cache . Thanks for the help @bknights